# An individual is paid biweekly but quits with 2 days left in the cycle. Do those 2 days of wages need to be repaid?

Tags: salary, quitting

One quits their job for personal reasons on a Wednesday and is paid on a biweekly basis, so one had been paid through the Friday of the week that one quit. So one was paid for Thursday and Friday inadvertently because payroll was done in advance. Employer is demanding those two days of wages to be repaid.

Would those wages need to be repaid? Let's say the individual in question is located and was employed in NY.

Comment: Most likely yes they would need to be repaid but to be sure, you would need to consult a labor lawyer or the state Labor department.

Comment: Are you sure that you are being paid in advance? Most biweekly pay schedules pay for the prior two weeks, so you would receive a smaller paycheck two weeks after you quit.

Comment: They aren't saying they were paid in advance (as in paid today for the next two weeks). The OP is saying that the payroll was already submitted/completed before the company knew the employee was leaving - ie the transfer amounts had already been sent to the bank.

Comment: "Employer is demanding" or "Employee is demand" there is a huge difference.  If the employee worked two days they are owned salary prorated for the work they did.  If they worked an hour of a single day then walked out, then they would be owned, for that one hour of wage.  If the employer overpaid by X Days - 2 then they are owed that money by the employee.  If an employee was overpaid it is their responsible to resolve the situation, an employer has a legal case against them, said employee until said money is paid back is also responsible for tax on that income.

Answer (score 9):

> Would those wages need to be repaid?

**Yes.**

You are entitled to be paid for the days worked, but not for days which were not worked.

If the former employer wants the inadvertently overpaid money back, they are entitled to get it within a reasonable period of time.

It doesn't matter what the pay cycle is, nor when in the cycle the separation occurred.

Answer (score 4):

**You are paid for what you work**

You are paid on a 2 weekly cycle **normally** just because that's how frequently you're paid

However if you only work 1 day, you will still be paid for that one day. You will not be paid for 14 days just because you worked one of them, but equally you don't need to work for all 14 days in order to be paid for the ones you did work.

Meaning you should have been paid for 12 days if you didn't work for the last two (or 8 of the 10, if you only get paid for 5 days a week).

In this case, the employer presumably didn't know you were leaving until it was too late and they had already submitted the payment amounts/details to their bank, and it was too late to recall or adjust the payment - this is fairly common in some systems.

**By extension, then**, you have been overpaid. You've been paid for 2 days that you didn't work. That's a genuine mistake and isn't your money, and it must be repaid - both ethically and legally.

**TL;DR**: Yes, it must be repaid. They weren't wages because you didn't work for them, they are an accidental overpayment.

Make sure you ask for a tax refund